# how to open standard Google Map application from my application and after choose a location then redirect back to my application?

Tags: android, google-maps, location, maps

how to open standard Google Map application from my application and after choose a location then redirect back to my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is (as much I know) - **No you cannot do it**. You can just start Google maps by an intent but you cannot get back the data from it.
If you need something like this, you need to have **Google Maps API** and show maps directly in your app.

Comment: I am do not have a billing account in google cloud platform. Is it possible way, I think like this "how to open standard Google Map application from my application and after choose a location then redirect back to my application" ?.

Comment: As I said, it cannot be done. Use google maps API instead

Comment: Okay and Thank you for a response.. @s_o_m_m_y_e_e.

Comment: If that helped, kindly mark it as the correct answer!